# this code is working for 6656*3328 image size, if i increase the size to 13312*6656 then there comes an error. what could be the solution?

Tags: python, opencv, deep-learning, yolo

```
import cv2
import cv
import numpy as np

# Load YOLO
net = cv2.dnn.readNet("yolov3.weights", "yolov3.cfg")
classes = []
with open("coco.names", "r") as f:
    classes = [line.strip() for line in f.readlines()]
layer_names = net.getLayerNames()

outputlayers = [layer_names[i - 1] for i in net.getUnconnectedOutLayers()]

protopath = "MobileNetSSD_deploy.prototxt"
modelpath = "MobileNetSSD_deploy.caffemodel"
detector = cv2.dnn.readNetFromCaffe(prototxt=protopath, caffeModel=modelpath)

colors = np.random.uniform(0, 255, size=(len(classes), 3))

def main():
    # Load the image at 6656x3328 resolution
    img = cv2.imread("C:/Users/HP/Desktop/dissertation/paranoma images-2/test5.jpg")
 
    # Set the desired resolution
    desired_resolution = (13312, 6656)

    # Resize the image to the desired resolution
    img = cv2.resize(img, desired_resolution)

    (height, width) = img.shape[:2]

    blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(img, 0.007843, (width, height), 127.5)

    detector.setInput(blob)
    person_detections = detector.forward()

    net.setInput(blob)
    outs = net.forward(outputlayers)  #ERROR

    # Process YOLO detections
    class_ids = []
    confidences = []
    boxes = []
    person_count = 0   #change
    other = 0
    for out in outs:
        for detection in out:
            scores = detection[5:]
            class_id = np.argmax(scores)
            confidence = scores[class_id]
        
            if confidence > 0.5:
                if classes[class_id] not in ["person"]:
                    continue 

                center_x = int(detection[0] * width)
                center_y = int(detection[1] * height)
                w = int(detection[2] * width)
                h = int(detection[3] * height)

                x = int(center_x - w/2)
                y = int(center_y - h/2)

                boxes.append([x, y, w, h])
                confidences.append(float(confidence))
                class_ids.append(class_id)

    indexes = cv2.dnn.NMSBoxes(boxes, confidences, 0.4, 0.6)

    font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN
    for i in range(len(boxes)):
        if i in indexes:
            x, y, w, h = boxes[i]
            label = str(classes[class_ids[i]])
            if label == "person":
                color = colors[class_ids[i]]
                cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), color, 2)
                cv2.putText(img, label, (x, y + 30), font, 1, (255, 255, 255), 2)
                person_count += 1   #change
            else:
                print("other label", label)
                other += 1

    # Save the output as an image with the desired resolution
    cv2.imwrite('14Oct_output1.jpg', img)
    print("Person count - ", person_count) #change
    print("Other count - ", other)
    print("Pedestrians -", person_count - other)
    cv2.imshow("YOLO Result", img)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
main()
```

this code is working with the resolution or size of image `6656*3328`, but when i change the size to `13312*6656` this code shows the error as

```
[ERROR:0@193.794] global net_impl.cpp:1201 cv::dnn::dnn4_v20230620::Net::Impl::getLayerShapesRecursively OPENCV/DNN: [Convolution]:(conv_0): getMemoryShapes() post validation failed. inputs=1 outputs=1/1 blobs=1 inplace=0
[ERROR:0@193.804] global net_impl.cpp:1204 cv::dnn::dnn4_v20230620::Net::Impl::getLayerShapesRecursively     input[0] = [ 1 3 6656 13312 ]
[ERROR:0@193.804] global net_impl.cpp:1208 cv::dnn::dnn4_v20230620::Net::Impl::getLayerShapesRecursively     output[0] = [ 1 32 6656 13312 ]
[ERROR:0@193.804] global net_impl.cpp:1212 cv::dnn::dnn4_v20230620::Net::Impl::getLayerShapesRecursively     blobs[0] = CV_32FC1 [ 32 3 3 3 ]
[ERROR:0@193.811] global net_impl.cpp:1214 cv::dnn::dnn4_v20230620::Net::Impl::getLayerShapesRecursively Exception message: OpenCV(4.8.0) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\dnn\src\net_impl.cpp:1193: error: (-2:Unspecified error) in function 'void __cdecl cv::dnn::dnn4_v20230620::Net::Impl::getLayerShapesRecursively(int,class std::map<int,struct cv::dnn::dnn4_v20230620::detail::LayerShapes,struct std::less<int>,class std::allocator<struct std::pair<int const ,struct cv::dnn::dnn4_v20230620::detail::LayerShapes> > > &)'
>  (expected: 'total(os[i]) > 0'), where
>     'total(os[i])' is -1459617792
> must be greater than
>     '0' is 0

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\HP\Desktop\dissertation\GIT\GIT (code3)\AIComputerVision-master\14 oct test1.py", line 93, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\HP\Desktop\dissertation\GIT\GIT (code3)\AIComputerVision-master\14 oct test1.py", line 38, in main
    outs = net.forward(outputlayers)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.8.0) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\dnn\src\net_impl.cpp:1193: error: (-2:Unspecified error) in function 'void __cdecl cv::dnn::dnn4_v20230620::Net::Impl::getLayerShapesRecursively(int,class std::map<int,struct cv::dnn::dnn4_v20230620::detail::LayerShapes,struct std::less<int>,class std::allocator<struct std::pair<int const ,struct cv::dnn::dnn4_v20230620::detail::LayerShapes> > > &)'
>  (expected: 'total(os[i]) > 0'), where
>     'total(os[i])' is -1459617792
> must be greater than
>     '0' is 0
```

Comment: you don't have enough RAM for that.